# Delete all rows which hadn't been accessed in a certain amount of time

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to delete all the rows from a table that haven't been red or haven't been created within the last year. 
There is no column that indicates the last access date of a row.

Is there a way to accomplish this anyway the using some internal logs or anything like this in MS Access?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this. Access doesn't keep this sort of log (or any DBMS I know of).

You would need a "date_created" or "date_accessed" column to achieve this.

BTW, in a continuous form or datasheet view, **all** rows are read (or the filtered ones).